# How can we return reason for action denial from inside Laravel policy?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

Let's say we have action in the policy for our model that can return `false` in bunch of different scenarios:

```
class PostPolicy
{
    public function publish(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        if ($post->user_id !== $user->id) {
            return false;
        }

        return $post->show_at->lessThan(now());
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are denying this user his publishing rights in two cases: if it's not his post or if this post was prepared in advance for some future date that is not yet due.

How can I provide some context as to why authorization failed? Was it because we are not the owner or was it because it's not time yet for this post to be published?

```
$user->can('publish', $post); // if this returns false we don't know
                              // what caused authorization to fail.
```

It looks that Laravel policies by design doesn't have any way of doing that. But I am curious as to what workarounds there can possibly be so that we can have authorization logic (no matter how intricate) in one place (model's policy) and also get some context (i.e., custom error codes) when authorization fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was splitting some of the responsibilities between model and it's policy.

Policy ended up responsible for making sure user has the right to do a specific action. Nothing more or less:

```
class PostPolicy
{
    public function publish(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $post->user_id !== $user->id;
    }
}
```

Model on the other hand must have logic to check whether or not certain action can be performed with it:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    ...

    public function isPublishable()
    {
        return $this->show_at->lessThan(now());
    }

    ...
}
```

Therefore each post instance now can tell us whether or not it can be published. Lastly my `Post::publishBy(User $user)` action will include authorizing user for this action first and checking if this post can be published separately so that we can determine specific reason as to why publishing failed.

I feel like this design suits better, leaving Laravel policies to do only what they are supposed to be doing (authorizing user actions) and requiring models to be responsible for things that only concern them.

Answer (score 6):

In case any one needed,
apart from above accepted answer, in Laravel 7+, Gate can provide reasons for denial,

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#gate-responses

- `Gate::authorize()` calls will throw reason along with the exception with message provided in the `Response::deny(<message>)` call, the exception itself will be an `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException`
- `$user->can()` or `Gate::allows()` will give boolean
- `Gate::inspect()` will give full response

Given that you will now return a Gate Response object instead of boolean, Laravel will help on returning suitable response stated above.

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
```

Originally, you only return a boolean

```
<?php
class PostPolicy
{
    public function publish(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $post->user_id !== $user->id;
    }
}
```

By using Gate Response, you can now provide a reason

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
class PostPolicy
{
    public function publish(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $post->user_id === $user->id 
                 ? Response::allow() 
                 : Response::deny('You are not the author of the post.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If in controller you are using the policy like :

```
<?php 

$this->authorize('publish', Post::class)
```

Then laravel is going to have 403 HTTPResponse error.

What you should do is, one policy method should just be checking one validation case.

For example update your policy :

```
<?php
// Check if post he is trying to publish is his own
public function publishOwnPost(){...}

// Check if post is for future purpose
public function publicFuturePost(){...}
```

Then in controller do :

```
<?php


if(!$user->can('publishOwnPost', $post)){

   // Return custom error view for case 1
   return response()->view('errors.publishOwnPostError', $data, 403);
}

if(!$user->can('publishFuturePost', $post)){

   // Return custom error view for case 2
   return response()->view('errors.publishFuturePostError', $data, 403);
}

// Do further processing
```

Comment: This goes against what policy actions should be because now instead of one `publish` action authorization I will have to authorize multiple ones with different names.

All checks must be encapsulated inside single action in the policy. Otherwise maintaining the code you've provided will be a walking nightmare (imagine adding new publish authorization check when you are authorizing this action all over your project).

Comment: The motive of policy is granular level access permissions and control. Having one method validating 2 cases is ambiguous case in itself. The purpose of policy is just to tell if particular action is allowed or not. The responsibility of handling gos to controller. 

But what you now have will still be a very viable solution if you do not want to handle the 2 validation cases differently. In your case I am comfortable in the solution I had provided :)

Comment: But what happens when new authorization checks are introduced? Or some are no longer required? It will lead to changing all authorization checks in all of the project for this action. What if one of them gets overlooked or missed? Or maybe someone can mess up the order (priority) on them and so on.

I thank you for you contribution, but this is not a centralized way to go about such a problem. Having that kind of burden (to know which policy methods exist and are related to specific action) each time action must be authorized just smells trouble.

Comment: Totally depends on your solution. Laravel's policy is there so that laravel can handle the 403 forbidden http response. That is not responsibility of policy to tell why it was rejected. So I kinda understand your worry of maintaining the code for longer run. You can make a separate function to validate and use it overall the website. So if the validation for publish changes that only function is responsible. I would be happy to know if there is any better solution to this, but at the moment I feel what I said would be easiest for you.